# Send template driven form's field value

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have used Angular template driven dynamic form as shown below.I know how to send all values of form when pressing a `submit` button. We can send it as `f.value`. But I need to send the `textbox` value on this method `(click)="goToNext(sendUserEnteredTextBoxValueHere)"`.How can I do that?

**Note:** Here I'm using one-way data binding.

```
<form novalidate #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">

 <div *ngIf="question?.type=='textfield'">
   <ion-label>a. {{question?.prompt}}*</ion-label>
   <ion-input type="text" placeholder="{{question?.prompt}}" name="{{question?.name}}" ngModel> </ion-input>
   <button ion-button type="button" (click)="goToNext(sendUserEnteredTextBoxValueHere)"></ion-icon></button>
  </div>

  //having so many other dynamic HTML elements   

<button ion-button type="submit" [disabled]="f.invalid">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign ngModel with name and send it to the function. But If you are using the same class, you dont need to send any values from function however it will be availbel in class itself. Check below the way

```
<form novalidate #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">

    <div *ngIf="question?.type=='textfield'">
      <ion-label>a. {{question?.prompt}}*</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" placeholder="{{question?.prompt}}" name="{{question?.name}}" #name="ngModel"> </ion-input>
      <button ion-button type="button" (click)="goToNext(currentQuestionCode,name)"><ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon></button>
    </div>

    //having so many other dynamic HTML elements   

    <button ion-button type="submit" [disabled]="f.invalid">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Here I'm not using `2-way data binding`.Because I don't have a model on `ts` side.It is a dynamic form.Then how can I handle it?

Comment: You can create a  local template variable and pass ngModel value into it and later you can pass name variable to your function..Check updated code

Comment: It seems your solution is working.But how can I give local variables for dynamic form elements?Then I have to use names like name1,name2... and so on.Hope which is not a good thing. Can't we have another workaround for this.I have a lot of form elements.Thanks for your feedback.